# Calculating only values that are not null in field using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser, null

I'm using ArcGIS Pro, the field calculator. I want to populate a hydrant layer with hydrant inspection data.
I have two fields from a joined table: field 1 and field 2.  I want to populate field 1 with the values from field 2, but only if the values ARE NOT Null. Basically I want to preserve the values in field 1 if the corresponding value in field 2 is Null.  I've been trying slight variations of the python code below.  But it just populates field 1 with all of field 2 whether there are nulls or not.

I'm a beginner when it comes to Python.

Codeblock:

```
def reclass(f1,f2):
        if f2 is not None:
            return f2
        else:
            pass
```

Expression:

```
reclass(!field1!,!field2!)
```

Comment: This can be done by using a [Python conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), a.k.a., ternary operator, in the expression block, no code block needed:  `!field1! if !field2! is None else !field2!`

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out!

Expression:

```
Reclass(!field1!,!field2!)
```

Codeblock:

```
 def Reclass(f1,f2):
        if f2 is None:
            return f1
        else: 
            return f2
```

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of Katie's answer if you want to add text to non-null fields

```
def Reclass(RMNM):
        if RMNM is None:
            return RMNM
        else: 
            return ("RM of " + RMNM)
```